# Find the longest line in 2D (MxM) array (vertical, horizontal, or diagonal)

Tags: java, matrix, time-complexity

**Find the length of the longest line with given square (MxM) matrix. (vertical, horizontal, or diagonal allowed) (Length of the longest line = number of consecutive 1's)**

i.e.) 
input:

```
{
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0},
{0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
{1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0},
{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
}
```

output: 7 (The 4th horizontal row is the longest line in this case.)

My java code:

```
public class LongestLine {
    private int hmax = 0;
    private int vmax = 0;
    private int rdmax = 0; // right down direction
    private int ldmax = 0; // left down direction


    public int longestLine(int[][] grid) {

        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                if(grid[i][j] == 1) update(grid, i, j);
            }
        }

        return Math.max(Math.max(hmax, vmax), Math.max(rdmax, ldmax));
    }

    private void update(int[][] grid, int i, int j) {
        int h = 1, v = 1, rd = 1, ld = 1;

        if(j < grid[i].length - 1 && grid[i][j+1] == 1) h = updateH(grid, i, j+1, h);
        if(i < grid.length - 1 && grid[i+1][j] == 1) v = updateV(grid, i+1, j, v);
        if(j < grid[i].length - 1 && i < grid.length - 1 && grid[i+1][j+1] == 1) 
            rd = updateRD(grid, i+1, j+1, rd);
        if(j > 0 && i < grid.length - 1 && grid[i+1][j-1] == 1) 
            ld = updateLD(grid, i+1, j-1, ld);

        hmax = Math.max(h, hmax);
        vmax = Math.max(v, vmax);
        rdmax = Math.max(rd, rdmax);
        ldmax = Math.max(ld, ldmax);
    }

    private int updateH(int[][] grid, int i, int j, int h) {
        h++;
        if(j < grid[i].length - 1 && grid[i][j+1] == 1) h = updateH(grid, i, j+1, h);
        return h;
    }

    private int updateV(int[][] grid, int i, int j, int v) {
        v++;
        if(i < grid.length - 1 && grid[i+1][j] == 1) v = updateV(grid, i+1, j, v);
        return v;
    }

    private int updateRD(int[][] grid, int i, int j, int rd) {
        rd++;
        if(j < grid[i].length - 1 && i < grid.length - 1 && grid[i+1][j+1] == 1) 
            rd = updateRD(grid, i+1, j+1, rd);
        return rd;
    }

    private int updateLD(int[][] grid, int i, int j, int ld) {
        ld++;
        if(j > 0 && i < grid.length - 1 && grid[i+1][j-1] == 1) 
            ld = updateLD(grid, i+1, j-1, ld);
        return ld;
    }
}
```

**My code seems to work, but I'm not sure if this is the most efficient code. Do you think this is OK? Or are there any faster/simpler implementation? (Answer in Java format preferred.)**

Comment: This question is not clear. What do you mean by the length of the longest line here?

Comment: If you have working code and want to reviewed, you should ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RavindraRanwala A line is a sequence of 1's.

Comment: @Andreas Got it thanks.

Comment: With dynamic programming you can implement it with O(M^2) time complexity and  O(M) memory complexity.

Comment: BTW. recursive code is NOT effective. Even if you keep the current logic but resolve the recursions, your code will much faster.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to use backtracking technique because it try all possible way in the board
please  read about backtracking